# How to get max value in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
>>> AuthorizedEmail.objects.filter(group=group).values('added')
[{'added': datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 19, 13, 8, 7)}, 
{'added': datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 19, 13, 8, 7)}, 
{'added': datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 19, 13, 7, 23)}, 
{'added': datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 19, 13, 8, 7)}]
```

What would be the best way to get the max value here? In python or in the ORM?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
>>> from django.db.models import Max
>>> AuthorizedEmail.objects.aggregate(Max('added'))
```

And to fetch the value in the template:

```
{{ item.added__max }}
```

Answer (score 9):

`latest` returns the latest object in the table according to the `added` date:

```
AuthorizedEmail.objects.filter(group=group).latest('added')
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's question, but is the right solution for my problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
AuthorizedEmail.objects.filter(group=group).order_by('-added')[0]
```

Comment: AuthorizedEmail.objects.filter(group=group).order_by('-added').first()

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet